# Swift can't find variable

Tags: swift, variables, save, userdefaults

why is this not working? It's made to check if a variable with the name "language" exists at the UserDefaults.

```
func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
     return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
}   

if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: language!) == true { //<-- Cannot find 'language' in scope
     print("Language variable: true")
}else {
     print("Language variable: false")
}
```

I tried to add this before the error:

```
let language: String?
```

... but it also hadn't worked.

Thank you for everyone who can help!

Comment: Where is written this code? Currently `if isKeyPresentInUser...` is written from "nowhere". It's not inside a function?

Comment: not about your question but the language is Optional so make it with "var" not "let"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for your support. I found my own way to fix that. Hopefully it's well enough so that others later also can use this.

First, I created a new class called "UserDefaultsMonitoring.swift"

```
import Foundation

final class UserDefaultsMonitor {
    static let shared = UserDefaultsMonitor()
    
    public private(set) var isLanguage: Bool = false
    
    public func startMonitoring() {
        self.isLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Language") != nil
    }
}
```

Then I added to the already by xCode created class called "ExtentionDelegate.swift" the following:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
     // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     UserDefaultsMonitor.shared.startMonitoring()
}
```

And last but not least I used this to check if the searched key exists:

```
if !UserDefaultsMonitor.shared.isLanguage {
     NoLanguageSet()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UserDefaults is about storing and retrieving **value** of variable (not it's name) using chosen key, being some String. You store the value of variable using chosen key, and then retrive stored value using the same key. What about using something like this?

```
let language = "language"
```

`isKeyPresentInUserDefaults` will return true if you (someone) previously stored value in UserDefaults using:

```
UserDefaults.default.set(someVariable, forKey: language)
```

Some complication (to be read as soon as text above is clear): Of course, if value of `someVariable` was `nil`, function returns false, as value `nil` is stored in UserDefaults. But I suppose you're not going to store Optional variable with value `nil` in UserDefaults.